# How can I use .id of existing User with mongoose Model populate?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have saved users

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f970abfe1c19f452cf715eb"), "username" : "Jean1", "email" : "mtigana@aol.com", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1"), "username" : "Jim", "email" : "jimmana@aol.com", "__v" : 0 }
```

When I create Post

```
async function createPost() {
      await Post.create({title: 'Vou come Karen! ',
        body: 'What a wonderful life!',
        postedBy: 5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1,
        comments
      });
```

This gives error

```
        postedBy: 5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1,
                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

How to releate postedBy field with user Jim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

Ex:-

```
 await Post.create({title: 'Vou come Karen! ',
        body: 'What a wonderful life!',
        postedBy:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f97c071bad24d1a81b25dd1'),
        comments
      });
```